# "Questions on Empty are expected to generally relate to ,"

Tags: bug, status-completed, close-reasons

On a closed question, I see the following auto-text:

> Questions on Empty are expected to generally relate to , within the scope defined in the faq.

It looks like the name of the site and the scope description are stood in for with some sort of null pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good catch - it is all fixed now. (:

Comment: In the [example](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/7859/498) you linked, the site name pointer is correct, but not the scope pointer: "Questions on Jewish Life and Learning - Stack Exchange are expected to generally relate **to ,** within ..."

Comment: @IsaacMoses, picky, picky! (;  (really fixed now!)

Comment: Thanks!